# performSegueWithIdentifier not always working in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I've got a UITableView with a few cells on there and I want to segue to another screen whenever I push one of these cells. My code works, sort of.... But sometimes I've to push the cell twice in order to segue!

Does anyone know why?

```
func tableView(gamesListTableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row < GamesList.count) {
        self.gameState = GamesList[indexPath.row];
        performSegueWithIdentifier("presentGame", sender: self);
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Swipe!", message: "Swipe Invite To The Left", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in }
        alert.addAction(alertAction)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { () -> Void in }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "presentGame") {
        var presentGame = segue.destinationViewController as! Game;
        presentGame.gameState = self.gameState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is known issue in the wild that require dummy dispatch_async call as workaround - http://openradar.appspot.com/19563577 likely in future versions it will go away. Here is how code with a workaround will looks like:

```
func tableView(gamesListTableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row < GamesList.count) {
        self.gameState = GamesList[indexPath.row];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {}); //http://openradar.appspot.com/19563577 
        performSegueWithIdentifier("presentGame", sender: self);
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Swipe!", message: "Swipe Invite To The Left", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in }
        alert.addAction(alertAction)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { () -> Void in }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to use the that function in my code?

Comment: Ops sorry man I messed it up :) your code in swift, I provided objc snippet. i will edit my post for your code in a second.

Comment: Thanks for editing. It wouldn't compile though because I had to add a bunch of self. to the variables used. I ended up using this instead ^

Comment: Hm, the only thing that there is self references captured by closure, so you will need weak references all around. :-/

Comment: ok, looks like you figured it out :) glad that I was able to help.